# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCollection() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, error, collection, php-7

i have problem when create model databse
Lesson3/Test/Block/Monblock.php

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        $retour='';
        /* we are doing the query to select all elements of the pfay_test table (thanks to our model test/test and we sort them by id */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_celebes','asc');
        /* then, we check the result of the query and with the function getData() */
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $retour .= $data->getData('name').' '.$data->getData('surename').' '.$data->getData('phone').'<br />';
        }
        //i return a success message to the user thanks to the Session.
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Congratulation !!');
        return $retour;
     }
}
```

Lesson3/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Lesson3_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lesson3_Test>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <lesson3>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lesson3_Test</module>
                 <frontName>lesson3</frontName>
              </args>
           </lesson3>
       </routers>
       <layout>
         <updates>
              <lesson3>
                   <file>lesson3.xml</file>
               </lesson3>
          </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <lesson3>
          <class>Lesson3_Test_Block</class>
        </lesson3>
      </blocks>
    <models>
        <lesson3>
            <class>Lesson3_Test_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Test_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </lesson3>
        <lesson3_mysql4>
            <class>Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <test>
                    <table>celebes</table>
                </test>
            </entities>
        </lesson3_mysql4>
    </models>
        <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
    <resources>
        <!-- connection to write -->
        <lesson3_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </lesson3_write>
        <!-- connection to read -->
       <lesson3_read>
          <connection>
             <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
       </lesson3_read>
    </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Lesson3/Test/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Lesson3_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
   }

    public function testAction()
    {
        echo 'test mymethod';
    }
}
```

Lesson3/Test/Model/Test.php

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Lesson3/Test/Model/Mysql4/Test.php

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('test/test', 'id_celebes');
     }
}
```

Lesson3/Test/Model/Mysql4/Test/Collection.php

```
<?php
class Celebes_Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on config
`<resourceModel>Test_mysql4</resourceModel>`.

I change it with this `<resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>` and its work

Answer (score 4):

you declared your models like this:

```
 <models>
    <lesson3>
        <class>Lesson3_Test_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>Test_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </lesson3>
    <lesson3_mysql4>
        <class>Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <test>
                <table>celebes</table>
            </test>
        </entities>
    </lesson3_mysql4>
</models>
```

this means the alias for the models is `lesson3` (the first tag under `<models>`).
So you need to instantiate your models like this:

```
Mage::getModel('lesson3/model_name_here');
```

In your case, instead of

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()....
```

you need to use

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('lesson3/test')->getCollection()....
```

Also replace in `Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test`  this

```
$this->_init('test/test', 'id_celebes');
```

with this

```
$this->_init('lesson3/test', 'id_celebes');
```

and in `Celebes_Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection` and `Lesson3_Test_Model_Test` this

```
$this->_init('test/test');
```

with this

```
$this->_init('lesson3/test');
```

Or, instead of all the above you can replace in `config.xml` the tag `<lesson3>` under `<models>` and `<blocks>` with `<test>`.

**[EDIT]**

`<resourceModel>Test_mysql4</resourceModel>` should be `<resourceModel>lesson3_mysql4</resourceModel>`

Comment: I've tried your solution to change 'lesson3' on  my block and models, but I  find the error like this Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setOrder() on boolean

Comment: i have table 'celebes' and structur is like this : 
id_celebes <int>
name <varchar(50)>
surename <varchar(50)>
phone <varchar(20)>

and my table is empty

Comment: i have edit model Collection.php from Celebes_Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection to Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection 
but i still find error "setOrder() on boolean"

Comment: if i delete "->setOrder('id_celebes','asc');", a page is run but data of 'celebes' is did not show

Comment: that happens because `->getCollection()` returns null for some reason. I'm looking on it. It has to be a configuration issue though.

Comment: See my edit. Maybe you get some progress.

Comment: ihave following your progres

$collection = Mage::getModel('lesson3/test')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_celebes','asc');

$this->_init('lesson3/test', 'id_celebes');

$this->_init('lesson3/test');

but i still find same error :)
$this->_init('lesson3/test');

Comment: i have try crush    Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test    and     Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection   after   clear setOrder('id_celebes','asc');  but error no detected.______________but if i crush Lesson3_Test_Model_Test  after  clear setOrder('id_celebes','asc'); i found error page

Comment: i suspect the issue is  ||||| <lesson3_mysql4>
   <class>Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
   <entities>
    <test>
     <table>celebes</table>
    </test>
   </entities>
  </lesson3_mysql4> ||||| because if call table with |||| $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  
  $result = $connection->query('select * from celebes')->fetchAll();
  Zend_Debug::dump($result); |||| on indexController this succes